# Creating options page for BHO

Tags: bho

I am creating an IE browser extension using BHO,
I would like to create an option page like the on chrome or firefox. 
I want this page to be accessible using manage add-ons page like it works in chrome and firefox. Is it possible? how do I do that?
I am using visual studio ATL and c++

Answer (score 1):

Your Best Best is adding Context Menu or Tools Menu Item.
Basically There is no Standard IE Options Dialog that you can merge your stuff into.
you are gone have to have your own dialog.
as a warning starting with IE10 and IE11. your IE-Addons (BHO,Menu,Toolbar,DeskBank) will not have any access to registry or file system.
if you need to save some stuff. you are gone have to probably create a broker process.
for instance you need to create a windows service that listen on a socket (maybe some random port) and yo you can communicate with it from your options dialog on what to save and what to read.
[Inserting context Menus into IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Inserting Menu Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)